# Turning multiple rows into a string by merging on ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, subset, lookup

Table1:(there are hundreds of IDs)

```
 participant_id hpo_term              year_of_birth  affected_relative   genome
    123         kidney failure          2000               Y                38
    123         hand tremor             2000               Y                38
    123         kidney transplant       2000               Y                38
    432         hypertension            1980               N                37
    432         exotropia               1980               N                37
    432         scissor gait            1980               N                37
```

I have two look-up tables:(with hundreds of values in each)

Renal lookup:

```
kidney failure
kidney transplant
hypertension
```

Non-renal lookup(with hundreds of values in each):

```
hand tremor
exotropia
scissor gait
```

Desired outcome:

```
participant_id kidney_hpo_term                   non_kidney_hpo_term    year_of_birth affected_relative   genome
123            kidney failure;kidney transplant  hand tremor            2000              Y                 38
432            hypertension                      exotropia;scissor gait 1980              Y                 37
```

Initially I tried:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
pt.data %>% 
   mutate(kidney = hpo_term %in% kidney.hpo) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = kidney, values_from = hpo_term,
               values_fn = function(x)paste(x,collapse = ";"), values_fill = NA) %>%
   setNames(c("participant_id","Kidney","Non.kidney"))
```

with `kidney.hpo <- read.delim("kidney_hpo_terms.txt", header = F)`

But I get "Error in values_fn[[value]] ; object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Not sure what I am doing wrong and your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to say with your data.

First, your table1 has duplicated columns: `year_of_birth`, `affected_relative`, and `genome` are the same for a given participant.

This should better be stored in a separate table, which I named `table1_short`.

For your very question, it is only a matter of checking whether a term is in a vector, which is done using `%in%`.

Here is how you could write the code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
table1=read.table(header=T, text="
participant_id hpo_term              year_of_birth  affected_relative   genome
123         'kidney failure'          2000               Y                38
123         'hand tremor'             2000               Y                38
123         'kidney transplant'       2000               Y                38
432         hypertension              1980               N                37
432         exotropia                 1980               N                37
432         'scissor gait'            1980               N                37")

table1_short = table1 %>% select(-hpo_term) %>% group_by(participant_id) %>% slice(1)
table1_long = table1 %>% select(1:2)

renal_lookup = c("kidney failure", "kidney transplant", "hypertension")
nonrenal_lookup = c("hand tremor", "exotropia", "scissor gait")


table1_long %>% 
  group_by(participant_id) %>% 
  summarise(
    kidney_hpo_term = hpo_term[hpo_term %in% renal_lookup] %>% paste(collapse=";"),
    non_kidney_hpo_term = hpo_term[hpo_term %in% nonrenal_lookup] %>% paste(collapse=";")
  ) %>% 
  left_join(table1_short, by="participant_id")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   participant_id kidney_hpo_term                  non_kidney_hpo_term    year_of_birth affected_relative genome
#>            <int> <chr>                            <chr>                          <int> <chr>              <int>
#> 1            123 kidney failure;kidney transplant hand tremor                     2000 Y                     38
#> 2            432 hypertension                     exotropia;scissor gait          1980 N                     37
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Running your code I get the final table but the hpo_term columns (kidney and non_kidney are blank). To read in the lookup tables I am using kidney.hpo <- read.delim("kidney_hpo_terms.txt", header = F). Is there a problem with characters?

Comment: @tacrolimus `read.delim()` returns a dataframe so you might want to select the first column. Sorry, without a reproducible example, there is not much better I can do.

Comment: That solved it thanks! Apologies for not being able to share code. I work in an airlock on a HPC and it's uper hard to get data out! You've been really helpful and I really appreciate you taking the time to answer. Time to read up on tidyverse!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `dcast` in `data.table` as follows:

```
dtt[, group := paste0(
    ifelse(hpo_term %in% kidney_hpo, 'kidney', 'non_kidney'), '_hpo_term')]
dcast(dtt, ... ~ group, value.var = 'hpo_term',
    fun.aggregate = paste, collapse = ';')
#    participant_id year_of_birth affected_relative genome                  kidney_hpo_term
# 1:            123          2000                 Y     38 kidney failure;kidney transplant
# 2:            432          1980                 N     37                     hypertension
#       non_kidney_hpo_term
# 1:            hand tremor
# 2: exotropia;scissor gait"
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. When I try your solution I get an extra column at the end of just "non_kidney_term" with all the terms, with multiple terms with multiple repeated IDs